# How was the sea depth under the North Pole ice sheets measured?

Tags: geography, measurements, ice-sheets

Google Earth doesn't show the ice sheets of the North Pole, but the undersea depth. How was this depth measured, when most of this area is covered by ice all year round?

[image]

Comment: https://phys.org/news/2020-07-depth-arctic-ocean.html and here https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/bathymetry/arctic/ibcao_2002_mtg.pdf